# obtain the result of voice recognition in android

Tags: android

I want to obtain the result of the service voice recognition.I mean I want to obtain what the user say. I try a code

```
ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
if(matches.get(i).equals("funky monkey")){
Toast.makeText(this,"Excelent !",2000).show();
```

But I don't understand this line  if(matches.get(i).equals("funky monkey")) 
Can you help me to understand this line or to help me by other solution
thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line checks whether the string positioned in the i-th place in `matches` (`matches.get(i)`) is the same as the string "funky monky" (`equals("funky monky")`)

Comment: I don't understand why equals("funky monky"). If we should use this String  "funky monky" because it's default string or  can change this String

Comment: It is dependent on the purpose of the application. This code seems like a demo app, that checks whether the voice recognition detected the words funky monkey or not. If you wait for other string, then you can change it.